# Changing color of UI with onTapGesture

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've been trying to find a way to change the color of every flashcard in my app. I am struggling with understanding how to use @Binding, which I believe is the best solution. I ended up creating static variables in my Card struct, which allows me to change the card colors via onTapGesture actions. It seems very slow and I know there has to be a better way to accomplish this. Below is my code. **The action for changing the color is inside the Circle() in ContentView.** Thank you in advance. **Also could someone please tell me how to resize screenshots to post in here? The solutions online make my screenshots super blurry so I hate uploading them**

**CardView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct CardView: View {
    let card: Card
    var removal: (() -> Void)? = nil
    
    @State private var isShowingAnswer = false
    @State private var changeColors = false
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
                .fill(LinearGradient(colors: [Card.gradCs[Card.selec][0].opacity(1 - Double(abs(offset.width / 50))), Card.gradCs[Card.selec][1].opacity(1 - Double(abs(offset.width / 50)))], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous).fill(offset.width > 0 ? .green : .red))
                .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25)), radius:6, x:1, y:8)
            
            VStack(spacing: 20){
                Text(card.prompt)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.8))
                
                if isShowingAnswer {
                    Text(card.answer)
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8947916626930237, green: 0.8666666746139526, blue: 1, alpha: 1)))
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
        .frame(width: 450, height: 250)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(Double(offset.width / 5)))
        .offset(x: offset.width * 5, y: 0)
        .opacity(2 - Double(abs(offset.width / 50)))
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { gesture in
                    offset = gesture.translation
                }
                .onEnded { _ in
                    if abs(offset.width) > 100 {
                        removal?()
                    } else {
                        offset = .zero
                    }
                }
            )
        .onTapGesture {
            isShowingAnswer.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct CardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CardView(card: Card.example)
            .previewInterfaceOrientation(.portraitUpsideDown)
    }
}
```

**ContentView**

```
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    func stacked(at position: Int, in total: Int) -> some View {
        let offset = Double(total - position)
        return self.offset(x: 0, y: offset * 10)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.accessibilityDifferentiateWithoutColor) var differentiateWithoutColor
    @State private var cards = Array(repeating: Card.example, count: 10)
    
    @State private var timeRemaining = 100

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    @State private var isActive = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("\(timeRemaining / 60):\(timeRemaining % 60, specifier: "%02d")")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                        .padding(.vertical, 5)
                        .background(.black.opacity(0.75))
                        .clipShape(Capsule())
                    
                    Circle()
                        .fill(LinearGradient(colors: Card.gradCs[Card.selec], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation {
                                if Card.selec == 0 {
                                    Card.selec = 1
                                } else {
                                    Card.selec = 0
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                }
                ZStack {
                    ForEach(0 ..< cards.count, id: \.self) { index in
                        CardView(card: cards[index]) {
                            withAnimation {
                                removeCard(at: index)
                                print(self.offset())
                            }
                        }
                        .stacked(at: index, in: cards.count)
                    }
                }
                .allowsHitTesting(timeRemaining > 0)
                
                if cards.isEmpty {
                    Button("Start Again", action: resetCards)
                        .padding()
                        .background(.white)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .clipShape(Capsule())
                }
            }
            if differentiateWithoutColor {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                            .padding()
                            .background(.black.opacity(0.7))
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
                            .padding()
                            .background(.black.opacity(0.7))
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .padding()
                }
            }
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { time in
            guard isActive else { return }
            // Use if let when the non-nil case is valid. Use guard when the nil case represents some sort of error.
            // use guard when there should only be one result.. use if when you need ELSE to do something
            if timeRemaining > 0 {
                timeRemaining -= 1
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newPhase in
            if newPhase == .active {
                if cards.isEmpty == false {
                    isActive = true
                }
            } else {
                isActive = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    func removeCard(at index: Int) {
        cards.remove(at: index)
        
        if cards.isEmpty {
            isActive = false
        }
    }
    
    func resetCards() {
        cards = Array(repeating: Card.example, count: 10)
        timeRemaining = 100
        isActive = true
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**Card**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Card {
    let prompt: String
    let answer: String
    
    static var example = Card(prompt: "What is the name of Chicago's NFL Team?", answer: "Da Bears")
    static var gradCs = [[Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.6039215922355652, green: 0.49803921580314636, blue: 1, alpha: 1)), Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.49803924560546875, blue: 1, alpha: 1))], [Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.6039215922355652, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)), Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.6039215922355652, green: 0.49803921580314636, blue: 1, alpha: 1))]]
    static var selec = 0
}
```

Comment: Resize screenshots in Preview, with `Tools > Adjust Size`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

binding is a possible way to change colors, but I prefer the use of `ObservableObject`
to manage the set of Cards and their color selection.
The code in my answer shows how to use a `ObservableObject` `CardManager` to change all cards color
resulting from your selection in `Circle`.

```
// manages the cards and all cards color selection
class CardManager: ObservableObject {
    let gradCs = [[Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.6039215922355652, green: 0.49803921580314636, blue: 1, alpha: 1)), Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.49803924560546875, blue: 1, alpha: 1))], [Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.6039215922355652, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)), Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.6039215922355652, green: 0.49803921580314636, blue: 1, alpha: 1))]]
    
    @Published var cards = [Card]()
    @Published var selec = 0
  
    func getColorSet() -> [Color] {
        return gradCs[selec]
    }
}

struct Card {
    let prompt: String
    let answer: String

    static var example = Card(prompt: "What is the name of Chicago's NFL Team?", answer: "Da Bears")
}

extension View {
    func stacked(at position: Int, in total: Int) -> some View {
        let offset = Double(total - position)
        return self.offset(x: 0, y: offset * 10)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.accessibilityDifferentiateWithoutColor) var differentiateWithoutColor
    @StateObject var manager = CardManager()  // <--- here
    
    @State private var timeRemaining = 100

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    @State private var isActive = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("\(timeRemaining / 60):\(timeRemaining % 60, specifier: "%02d")")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                        .padding(.vertical, 5)
                        .background(.black.opacity(0.75))
                        .clipShape(Capsule())
                    
                    Circle()
                        .fill(LinearGradient(colors: manager.getColorSet(), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation {
                                if manager.selec == 0 {
                                    manager.selec = 1
                                } else {
                                    manager.selec = 0
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                }
                ZStack {
                    ForEach(0 ..< manager.cards.count, id: \.self) { index in
                        CardView(card: manager.cards[index]) {
                            withAnimation {
                                removeCard(at: index)
                                print(self.offset())
                            }
                        }
                        .stacked(at: index, in: manager.cards.count)
                    }
                }
                .allowsHitTesting(timeRemaining > 0)
                
                if manager.cards.isEmpty {
                    Button("Start Again", action: resetCards)
                        .padding()
                        .background(.white)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .clipShape(Capsule())
                }
            }
            if differentiateWithoutColor {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                            .padding()
                            .background(.black.opacity(0.7))
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
                            .padding()
                            .background(.black.opacity(0.7))
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .padding()
                }
            }
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { time in
            guard isActive else { return }
            // Use if let when the non-nil case is valid. Use guard when the nil case represents some sort of error.
            // use guard when there should only be one result.. use if when you need ELSE to do something
            if timeRemaining > 0 {
                timeRemaining -= 1
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newPhase in
            if newPhase == .active {
                if manager.cards.isEmpty == false {
                    isActive = true
                }
            } else {
                isActive = false
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            manager.cards = Array(repeating: Card.example, count: 10)  // <--- here
        }
        .environmentObject(manager)  // <--- here
    }
    
    func removeCard(at index: Int) {
        manager.cards.remove(at: index)
        
        if manager.cards.isEmpty {
            isActive = false
        }
    }
    
    func resetCards() {
        manager.cards = Array(repeating: Card.example, count: 10)
        timeRemaining = 100
        isActive = true
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var manager: CardManager // <--- here
    let card: Card
    var removal: (() -> Void)? = nil
    
    @State private var isShowingAnswer = false
    @State private var changeColors = false
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
                .fill(LinearGradient(colors: [manager.getColorSet()[0].opacity(1 - Double(abs(offset.width / 50))), manager.getColorSet()[1].opacity(1 - Double(abs(offset.width / 50)))], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous).fill(offset.width > 0 ? .green : .red))
                
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous).fill(offset.width > 0 ? .green : .red))
                .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25)), radius:6, x:1, y:8)
            
            VStack(spacing: 20){
                Text(card.prompt)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.8))
                
                if isShowingAnswer {
                    Text(card.answer)
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8947916626930237, green: 0.8666666746139526, blue: 1, alpha: 1)))
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
        .frame(width: 450, height: 250)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(Double(offset.width / 5)))
        .offset(x: offset.width * 5, y: 0)
        .opacity(2 - Double(abs(offset.width / 50)))
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { gesture in
                    offset = gesture.translation
                }
                .onEnded { _ in
                    if abs(offset.width) > 100 {
                        removal?()
                    } else {
                        offset = .zero
                    }
                }
            )
        .onTapGesture {
            isShowingAnswer.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response! This made the transition way smoother. Will use this route from now on.